# Compilation errors in the files included in the PyYAML-3.10 package while calling the module yaml from a python file

Tags: python

I am using the PyYAML-3.10 as part of a Python program on macOS 10, using Python version 2.7.10. I am not able to make sense of these compilation errors. Since PyYAML-3.10 is a stable version of PyYAML, it should give no compilation errors. The errors are listed below. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
File "pyR@TE.py", line 3, in <module>
    import yaml
  File "/Users/PyR@TE/pyrate-1.0.0/yaml/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .loader import *

  File "/Users/PyR@TE/pyrate-1.0.0/yaml/loader.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .reader import *

  File "/Users/PyR@TE/pyrate-1.0.0/yaml/reader.py", line 45, in <module>
    class Reader(object):

  File "/Users/PyR@TE/pyrate-1.0.0/yaml/reader.py", line 137, in Reader
    NON_PRINTABLE = re.compile('[^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\x7E\x85\xA0-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD]')    

raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: bad character range
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that PyYAMP-3.10 is not compatible with Python 2. (Did you mean "PyYAML", by the way? I could not find a reference to a "PyYAMP" package anywhere.) The compilation error you are seeing is from `re.compile` - when Python is trying to compile a regular expression.

I tried using the line in your error message containing `re.compile` in Python 2 and Python 3.

Python 2:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.compile('[^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\x7E\x85\xA0-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD]') 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 194, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 251, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: bad character range
>>>
```

Python 3:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.compile('[^\x09\x0A\x0D\x20-\x7E\x85\xA0-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD]') 
re.compile('[^\t\n\r -~\x85\xa0-\ud7ff\ue000-�]')
>>>
```

So your options are either to find a package that supports Python 2, or to upgrade your code to Python 3. I recommend upgrading, as Python 2 is no longer supported.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. You are correct I meant PyYAML-3.10 not PyYAMP-3.10. That was a typo. Unfortunately I don't know if the upgrade to Python 3 is an option here because the python code I am using has been tested only for Python 2.